# How to get the current persona of a user session in sitecore?

Tags: sitecore, personalization

I am using sitecore profile cards in the. Is there a way to fetch the current persona of the user that is mapped. I am using sitecore 6.6

Answer (score 2):

You can use the Analytics api to do this:

```cs
 var visit = Tracker.CurrentVisit;
 foreach (var profile in visit.Profiles)
 {  
   if (profile.ProfileName.ToLower() == "persona")
   {
      profile.UpdatePattern();

       // get the matching pattern text
      var matchingPattern = profile.PatternLabel;
   }
 }
```

Comment: *Can this answer be updated*? It looks like Tracker.CurrentVisit is obsolete. Whether I use Tracker.Current.Interaction or Tracker.CurrentVisit, when I try to iterate through visit.Profiles, the compiler says: `foreach statement cannot operate on variables of type 'IVisitProfiles' because 'IVisitProfiles' does not contain a public definition for 'GetEnumerator'`.